# Assign each number to 3 turtles

Tags: netlogo

I am creating a program that creates 1,500 "scientists" (turtles), in a world where there are 1500 "disciplines".

I need to assign each turtle a "discipline" as a number between 1-500, and ensure that there are 3 turtles for each discipline.

This means that set(random) isn't appropriate. Is there a primitive I can use?

Nevermind, I think I have figured it out.  Does this make sense?

```
  to set-discipline
    ask turtles [ set discipline -1 ]
    let unassigned turtles
    let current 1
    while [any? unassigned]
    [
      ask n-of (min (list group-size (count unassigned))) unassigned
        [ set discipline current ]
      set current current + 1
      set unassigned unassigned with [discipline = -1]
    ]
  end
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote and close vote; seems like a perfectly clear question to me.

Comment: John, you say there are 1500 disciplines, but I think you might mean 500. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but is very... unnetlogoish. `while` loops and indexes, in NetLogo, are often a sign that you're not taking full advantage of the capabilities of the language. At the very minimum, I would replace your `while` with a `foreach`:

```
ask turtles [ set discipline -1 ]
foreach n-values 500 [ 1 + ? ] [
  let unassigned turtles with [ discipline = -1 ]
  ask n-of (min (list group-size (count unassigned))) unassigned [
    set discipline ?
  ]    
]
```

You can check the result in the command center with:

```
observer> print remove-duplicates map [ count turtles with [ discipline = ? ] ] n-values 500 [ 1 + ? ]
[3]
```

But I would suggest taking it a step further.

Having disciplines just be numbers is a bit limiting. That is, of course, the sort of thing that you would do in a traditional mathematical model. But this is an ABM. And you have all of NetLogo at your disposal. You could make your disciplines... turtles! This would make your model much more flexible. Your disciplines could eventually be heterogeneous: having their own variables, by which they could differ from one another. And I think you'll find that replacing numbers with agents makes code more readable in general.

Here is a full example of what I have in mind:

```
breed [ scientists scientist ]
scientists-own [ my-discipline ]
breed [ disciplines discipline ]

to setup
  clear-all
  let nb-scientists 1500
  let nb-disciplines 500
  let group-size 3  
  create-scientists nb-scientists [
    set my-discipline nobody
  ]
  create-disciplines nb-disciplines [
    let unassigned scientists with [ my-discipline = nobody ]
    ask n-of (min (list group-size (count unassigned))) unassigned [ 
      set my-discipline myself
    ] 
  ]
end
```

You can check that it worked:

```
observer> setup
observer> print remove-duplicates [ count scientists with [ my-discipline = myself ] ] of disciplines
[3]
```

But you know what? If it was me, I would take it *another* step further, and make the relation between a scientist and its discipline an actual NetLogo `link`. This way, you could eventually envision a scientist belonging to (gasp!) more than one discipline. Here is what it would look like:

```
breed [ scientists scientist ]
breed [ disciplines discipline ]

to setup
  clear-all
  let nb-scientists 1500
  let nb-disciplines 500
  let group-size 3
  create-scientists nb-scientists
  create-disciplines nb-disciplines [
    let unassigned scientists with [ not any? my-links ]
    ask n-of (min (list group-size (count unassigned))) unassigned [ 
      create-link-with myself
    ] 
  ]
end
```

Don't you think the code is even nicer this way? And it works:

```
observer> print remove-duplicates [ count my-links ] of disciplines
[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

What Nicolas said. But consider also this alternate approach:

```
to test
  let disciplines reduce sentence map [(list ? ? ?)] n-values 500 [? + 1]
  ask turtles [
    set discipline first disciplines
    set disciplines butfirst disciplines
  ]
end
```

`ask` is in random order, so we don't need to shuffle the `disciplines` list.

Or, if the turtles don't exist yet and you're free to create them as you go:

```
to test
  let disciplines reduce sentence map [(list ? ? ?)] n-values 500 [? + 1]
  foreach shuffle disciplines [
    create-turtles 1 [ set discipline ? ]
  ]
end
```

In this one, we have to shuffle the list of disciplines, since the turtles are being created in who number order.